# MLFlow Recipe - FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: mlflow

I am trying to simply run the regression recipe from scratch on a Windows machine and am running into issues. I am using mlflow 2.1.1 via python 3.8.

After cloning the repo to a local folder. I tried to run jupyter.ipynb inside a jupyter notebook, but am experiencing an error at the data ingestion step. The following is the cell output:

```
FileNotFoundError                         Traceback (most recent call last)
\~\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\ipykernel_25776\\1674906274.py in \<module\>
\----\> 1 r.run("ingest")

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\recipes\\regression\\v1\\recipe.py in run(self, step)
276             regression_recipe.run()
277         """
\--\> 278         return super().run(step=step)
279
280     @experimental

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\recipes\\recipe.py in run(self, step)
84         self.\_steps = self.\_resolve_recipe_steps()
85         target_step = self.\_get_step(step) if step else self.\_get_default_step()
\---\> 86         last_executed_step = run_recipe_step(
87             self.\_recipe_root_path,
88             self.\_get_subgraph_for_target_step(target_step),

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\recipes\\utils\\execution.py in run_recipe_step(recipe_root_path, recipe_steps, target_step, template)
81         make_env.update(step.environment)
82     # Use Make to run the target step and all of its dependencies
\---\> 83     \_run_make(
84         execution_directory_path=execution_dir_path,
85         rule_name=target_step.name,

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\recipes\\utils\\execution.py in \_run_make(execution_directory_path, rule_name, extra_env, recipe_steps)
343     """
344     # Dry-run Make and collect the outputs
\--\> 345     process = \_exec_cmd(
346         \["make", "-n", "-f", "Makefile", rule_name\],
347         capture_output=False,

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\mlflow\\utils\\process.py in \_exec_cmd(cmd, throw_on_error, extra_env, capture_output, synchronous, stream_output, \*\*kwargs)
93             kwargs\["stderr"\] = subprocess.STDOUT
94
\---\> 95     process = subprocess.Popen(
96         cmd,
97         env=env,

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\subprocess.py in __init__(self, args, bufsize, executable, stdin, stdout, stderr, preexec_fn, close_fds, shell, cwd, env, universal_newlines, startupinfo, creationflags, restore_signals, start_new_session, pass_fds, user, group, extra_groups, encoding, errors, text, umask)
949                             encoding=encoding, errors=errors)
950
\--\> 951             self.\_execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
952                                 pass_fds, cwd, env,
953                                 startupinfo, creationflags, shell,

\~\\anaconda3\\lib\\subprocess.py in \_execute_child(self, args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds, pass_fds, cwd, env, startupinfo, creationflags, shell, p2cread, p2cwrite, c2pread, c2pwrite, errread, errwrite, unused_restore_signals, unused_gid, unused_gids, unused_uid, unused_umask, unused_start_new_session)
1418             # Start the process
1419             try:
\-\> 1420                 hp, ht, pid, tid = \_winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
1421                                          # no special security
1422                                          None, None,

FileNotFoundError: \[WinError 2\] The system cannot find the file specified
```

I tried updating the local.yaml ingestion location parameter to an absolute path, but same error.

```
INGEST_CONFIG:
using: parquet
location: "E:/recipes-examples/regression/data/sample.parquet"
```

Also tried to uninstall mlflow and reinstalling again (via pip).

I am quite new to using this recipe feature, so any advice and help very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue can be resolved by installing make on your machine. If you look at the output, you can see it is attempting to run a make command

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).